# Referencing first record in a group in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

In my report, in group footer, I want to add the sum on a column from all records in the group except the first one. How can I do that?

I tried **Insert - Subtotal** but it adds all records. If I can access the first record from each group, I can subtract it from the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're grouping your report by {Table.GroupID} and want to get the total per group, excluding the first record in the group, for {Table.NumericField}.

You can do this by creating a running total where:

1. Field to summarize: Table.NumericField; Type of summary: Sum
2. Set to evaluate with a formula: `previous({Table.GroupID})={Table.GroupID}`
3. Reset on change of group

The second step ensures that the group total is updated for every record *except* the first one in the group and can be read as "Only evaluate this running total when the previous record's GroupID is the same as the current record's GroupID.